# Cómo eliminar una imagen de imgur con la pi api desde python

Tags: python

Tengo un pequeño script qué sube las imagenes a imgur de forma anonima mediante enlace, pero tengo un pequeño problema y esque estoy intentando que mediante python poder borrar esa imagen, pero no lo puedo conseguir hacerlo.

este es el código que estoy usando:

```
import json
import requests

img = requests.post(
    'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json',
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Client-ID '},
    data = {
        'key': '',
        'title': 'prueba',
        'image': 'https://i.imgur.com/UxTY9vT.png'
        
    }
)

link = img.json()["data"]["link"]
print(link)
```

Debo colocar "**deletehash**" en algun lado de la api desde python, pero no se en donde

Alguien me podria ayudar?, muchas gracias!

Comment: leiste la documentacion? https://apidocs.imgur.com/#ca48883b-6964-4ab8-b87f-c274e32a970d

Comment: Sí, no entiendo muy bien, soy algo nueva con esto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ejemplo sacado de la documentacion:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.imgur.com/3/image/{{imageHash}}"

payload={}
files={}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer {{accessToken}}'
}

response = requests.request("DELETE", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

https://apidocs.imgur.com/#ca48883b-6964-4ab8-b87f-c274e32a970d

Comment: Igual mejor preguntarle que no entendio, porque la api pone el ejemplo clarito...

Comment: Una breve explicación vendría bien eh...